# Don't allow editing a textbox once it was filled, allow only entering new values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a mathematical calculation program.
I want to cycle between `TextBoxes` by pressing the tab button and it must select the value in the TextBox.
So I can use my program only for entering new values (I don't want to allow backspace to delete the current values).

Currently, there is a blinking cursor at the right of the value.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: You should be able to navigate between controls in a window, if the `tab stop` property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.SelectAll` when the text box got focus

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly my solution :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

And it will be useful for you to read more about TextBox and the other WinForms controls, here is a good start:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can make a textbox read-only by modifying the readonly behavior.  i.e.

textbox1.readonly = true

Then you just have to decide how/when to fire that bad boy up.  My questions for you are 1.) How many textboxes do you have?  2.) What is the range of values that you'll be putting into them (if there is one)? and 3.) Do I understand correctly:  you want to tab through text boxes but only be able to edit ones that are blank?  If so, something like this, maybe?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Problems here would be: 1 - you wouldn't be able to edit a value in the case of a typo (unless you changed it before hitting tab)  2 - You'd have to repeat this code for every single text box.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i think i couldnot tell you clearly my problem. this code makes read only after i come back to the textbox. please look at this picture: https://yadi.sk/d/cYGiA3MsgLZPL for example i write 45000 than i press tab button and i write 650 than i press tab button and i write 450 and then i press tab button to move over calculate button and make the calculation. after the calculation i will press the tab again and come to first textbox. here, i want to see textbox already selected (in the picture). so i dont have to delete the text.